# why I got unauthorized ionic angular

Tags: laravel, authentication, ionic-framework

this is my code

store function : page service

```
public store( data : any ) {
    return this.httpService.makePost('auth/personalInfo', data, true).pipe(map(
      res => {
        localStorage.setItem( 'token', res.headers.get('Authorization') );
        return res.json().personal_info;
      },
      error => {
        console.log("error stornig")
        localStorage.setItem( 'token', error.headers.get('Authorization') );
        return error.json();
      }
    ));
  }
```

makepost fun :

```
 public makePost( endpoint : string, data : any, authenticated : boolean = false ) {
    return this.http.post( `${this.url}${endpoint}`, data, { headers : this.getHeaders(authenticated) } );
  }
```

addinfo function page.ts

```
addInfo() {
      console.log("Hey mony");
          let data = {
            personal_info: this.personal_info
          }
          console.log(data);

          this.personalinfoService.store(JSON.stringify(data)).subscribe(
            personal_info => {
              console.log("working");
              this.personal_info = personal_info;
              this.loading.dismiss();
              this.dismiss( true );
            },
            error => {
              console.log("add info error");
            }
          );
    }
```

I'm get an error from add info I;m not sure why, is it because the serve? how can I check that

login and register function :

someone told me to convert response from JSON to JS object in login and register

```
login(email: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/login',
      {email: email, password: password}
    ).pipe(
      tap(token => {
        this.storage.setItem('token', token)
        .then(
          () => {
            console.log('Token Stored');
            console.log(token)
          },
          error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
        );
        this.token = token;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        console.log(token);
        return token;
      }),
    );
  }
  register(name: String, email: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/register',
      {name: name, email: email, password: password}
      )
  }
```

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/personalInfo 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Send your token to your header in `http` request.